# Azure machine learning. How can I see all columns

Tags: cortana-intelligence, azure-machine-learning-service

When I upload dataset with more then 100 columns I can see only part of them in the visualisation block. Can I see stats for all columns from dataset? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are an owner in the workspace, you can open your dataset in Python inside of a Jupyter Notebook. By the visualize should be an open in notebook button. Then just execute the code that is provided for you, and it should print your dataset. You can then also select specific columns to visualize as well.

Answer (score 0):

From https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-faq/

> When previewing results or data in the browser, the number of rows and columns is limited, why?
>
> Since the data is being transmitted to the browser and may be large, the data size is limited to prevent slowing down the ML studio. It is better to download the data/result and use Excel or another tool to visualize the entire data.